# How to return the `any` type what is I need when used `keyof`?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I don't know how to describe this question right, so please see the belows code

```
interface TestParams<T> {
  order?: keyof T
  attr1?: number
  attr2?: string
}

async function Test<T = any>(_obj: TestParams<T>): Promise<T> {
  return {} as T
}
```

```
Test({ order: 'id2' })

// function Test<{
//     id2: any;
// }>(_obj: TestParams<{
//     id2: any;
// }>): Promise<{
//     id2: any;
// }>
```

Why the `T` type is `{ id2: any; }` instead of `any`

The belows is my needs type

```
function Test<any>(_obj: TestParams<any>): Promise<PostgrestResponse<any>>
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gApynAWwwB5UA+ZAbwFgAoZZAeygBNoB+ALmQGsIBPRjDR0GcMGCgBGLshABXAgCNoo5OMkAmWViigA5nQC+dOnAz8QCZDHlWwwRiDSYwpZAF51IfmQAUAPqMSgBW3OhYuPhEpGQAlNzYUIwEwBgQsVRqUBBg8lDOlEbqGCK0JrR0EWB+lEys0NwA5MAsmk3IRnF0APQ9NnYIDk4uWMQ0tH0M062a3HA+ANy9-Ub+QaHhrlGEJBNT08iz80srnfGJyanp42eHx978y5OrZKa01cQLvrX1bFDNWYdLpnWz2RzOT7fdbBMKjHB4XZfHwXZBJFJpDLQoA)

**Update**

[new playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gApynAWwwB5UA+ZAbwFgAoZZAeygBNoB+ALjTobjDBQAjF2QgArgQBG0Xsn6CATKKxRQAczoBfOnTgYAniATIY442GCMQySFlJkAFAH1GUgFbd0WXPiKlkCAAPSBAWDGRzNhhQCBZkdmRVDWRuAGsIA0YYNDIASm5sKEYCYAwIByo5KAgwcSgbSi15CNRtXVo7MEdKJlZobgByYBZFQeQtPLoAemm0AAsUGQAbRgB3CLADAAcUMuQ1+f5kAEkxCDi4mbmzCysbLuI4EAMnVw8vTBw8QhIAIhGij++UKxVK5SeLzIHVAkFgiBQ3jAqB2KBo9GQgO4EmksgxIwAzNjJDIoO1Ol9SF8UbsnL1mGwoENAeNJkA)

**Update**

I added `U` which is `keyof T`, then implement my needs

```
interface TestParams<T> {
  order?: T
  attr1?: number
  attr2?: string
}

async function test<T = any, U = keyof T>(_obj: TestParams<T extends undefined ? string : U>): Promise<T> {
  return {} as T
}

test({ order: 'id2' })
// The belows type is what I needed
// function test<any>(_obj: TestParams<"id2">): Promise<any>

interface TestType {
  id2: number
  id3: number
}
test<TestType>({ order: 'id2' })
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gApynAWwwB5UA+ZAbwFgAoZZAeygBNoB+ALjTobjDBQAjF2QgArgQBG0Xsn6CATKKxRQAczoBfOnTgYAniATIY442GCMQySFlLIAvPJAGANMgCqT5AGsIBowwaGQAFAD6jFIAVtzoWLj4RA4QAB6QICwYyOZsMKAQLMjsyKoayNyeZACU3NhQjATAGBCkFDT0yFAQYOJQNpRa8tmo2rq0dmChlEys0NwA5MAsigvIWtV0APRbaAAWKDIANowA7tlgBgAOKM3Ip3v8yACSYhCFhdu7ZhZWNpPEOCuMKRGJxTA4PCEEgAImWihhNTqDSaLUBwPGoEgsEQKHiYFQ1xQHQY8O4Emksk6ywAzOTJDIoGMJhDSBDCTcwjNmGwoIt4WsNkA)

Comment: what do you want the type to be?

Comment: If I not set `T` value, I want to get type `function Test<any>(_obj: TestParams<string>): Promise<any>`
If I set `T` value, It should be get `function Test<TestType>(_obj: TestParams<keyof TestType>): Promise<TestType>`

Comment: This maybe not answer your question but using the `any` keyword defeats the purpose of type checking. See the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any). [Also helpful](https://dev.to/codiga/why-you-should-not-use-the-type-any-in-typescript-1li7)

Comment: I added another one U which is keyof T, then implement my needs, Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a generic constraint on `U` so TypeScript can't infer what string you gave to `TestParams`:

```
async function test<T = any, U extends keyof T = keyof T>(_obj: TestParams<U>): Promise<T> {
// +                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  return {} as T
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WkkajW)

Answer (score 0):

If `{ order: 'id2' }` is a `TestParams<T>` then, because `order` is `keyof T`, your `T` must be an interface that has a `id2` property. There is no restriction on the property's type, so it has to be `any`.

Thus, `T` is an interface with an `id2` property of any value. That's why `T` is `{ id2: any; }`.

Comment: You say that you're expecting `T` to be `any` instead, but I'm not sure where that `any` would be coming from. If you could elaborate on that, I might be able to help with getting there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
its from `Test` function default `T` value, but I'm not sure its right, I want to let `TestParams.order` value is `keyof T` and not change the `T` real types, if `T` is not set, it should be `any` and returned this type `any`

Comment: Right, but `T` *is* set. You're not setting it explicitly, but it's still there because the compiler infers it (like in my answer).

Comment: Is there a way to implement it? when I not set `T` value, the `order` value is `keyof T` and returned type is `T` instead of a `object` @ij7

Comment: Sorry, I'm really trying to understand what you're trying to do, but I don't think I do.

Comment: can u see the new playground in the question? I think the code maybe u can understand it @ijk

Comment: I'm not sure. Is this just about the return value from the function? You want it to return `Promise<any>` instead of `Promise<T>`? In that case, you could just write `Promise<any>` in the function definition.

Comment: But if I set `T` value, it should be return `Promise<T>` instead of `Promise<any>`

Comment: I added another one `U` which is `keyof T`, then implement my needs, Thanks for your reply again